# RHEL5 to RHEL6 Upgrade

Tags: linux, rhel, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade our RHEL 5.9 servers to RHEL 6.4. We have lots of third party software and mounted systems so it would be nice if we could upgrade without re-installing. I know RedHat doesn't support updates between major releases and we'll go the re-install route if all else fails. If I have a fresh install of 5.9 I'm able to upgrade to 6.4 without many issues using 'linux upgradeany' on a installation cd. But older physical servers that I have successfully cloned as a VM seem to hang while doing the package installation. At first it was hanging on polkit, so I removed all gui desktops with the intent on reinstalling after the upgrade. Now it's hanging on Cyrus-SASL. The logs don't give any useful information on why it is hanging.

There are some guides on updating but none have seemed to work for us.

http://bitc.bme.emory.edu/~lzhou/blogs/?p=203

http://www.it-hure.de/2011/10/update-rhel5-to-rhel6/

checked /tmp/anaconda.log, /tmp/syslog, /tmp/yum.log, /tmp/storage.log, /tmp/product.log and nothing seems to indicate why the update has halted.

If anyone's been able to upgrade successfully I would appreciate any advice you might have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I was able to get the upgrade to work.

1. Change inittab default to 3
2. Disable SElinux
3. Uninstall KDE and Gnome (you can reinstall after)
4. Install yum-utils (optional but suggested: run package-cleanup with the --leaves --orphans and --problems to see if there is anything you can remove before the upgrade)
5. Make sure all NFS mounts are unmounted and commented out in fstab.
6. Disable all unnecessary services. (re-enable after upgrade).
7. Reboot into the RHEL6 cd and run "linux upgrade any"
8. The upgrade will take a LONG time. For me it took almost 24+ hours. It will appear to hang at times but let it run.
9. Reboot
10. Remove abandoned packages (A list is [here](http://www.it-hure.de/2011/10/update-rhel5-to-rhel6/))
11. Do `yum remove kernel\*-2.6.18\*`
12. Run `yum distribution-synchronization --skip-broken`.
13. The results will give you a list of dependency problems. Work through the list and remove duplicates and remove and re-install the broken ones. Make sure to reinstall the dependencies removed with them as well.
14. Repeat step 12 until all problems are resolved and the  distribution-synchronization runs correctly.
15. Install KDE and GNOME (Or whatever desktop you will be using, if any).
16. Enable the services you disabled.
17. Uncomment the NFS mounts in fstab.
18. Re-enable SELinux
19. Change inittab back to default 5.
20. Change your grub.conf so that it's not doing a splash screen or quiet boot so that you can see if any services fail.
21. Reboot

I hope this helps others as this was a pain in my rear to get working. :)

Comment: Of course there will be some things missing or different so check carefully. For ldap I needed to get nss-pam-ldapd and pam-ldap.

Comment: For anyone looking at this in the future. After checking the logs after the upgrade, the reason it took so long to upgrade was because of ldap. Disable ldap before doing the upgrade and it'll go much quicker.

Answer (score 2):

We've never had any success in upgrading either. We abandoned trying to do this and just wipe the system clean and do a re-install.

Not what you want to hear but in the amount of time you're going to sink into trying to upgrade these systems, you could have probably laid out a plan of attack for getting 3rd party software off the system, wiped it, and then re-installed it after.

Comment: That's kinda where we're at, but I thought I'd throw it out there. Thanks for the input.